# Solution verification: Finding the probability of at least two shots hitting the target

Tags: probability, solution-verification

> Three shots are fired at a target. The odds in favour of the first hitting the target is $2:1$, that of the second hitting the target is $3:1$ and the odds against the third hitting the target is $2:1$. What is the probability of at least $2$ shots hitting the target?

What I did:-

Probability of at least two shits hitting the target= Probability of $ 2 $ shots hitting the target+ Probability of $3$ shots hitting the target

$2/3*3/4*1/3$ -----Probability of $2$ shots hitting the target

$2/3*1/4*2/3$------ Probability of $2$ shots hitting the target

$1/3*3/4*2/3$--------Probability of $2$ shots hitting the target

$2/3*3/4*2/3$-------Probability of $3$ shots hitting the target

Now I added all these four equation but answer isn't right

What has been done in the solution

$[2/3*3/4*2/3]+[2/3*1/4*1/3]+[2/3*3/4*1/3]=23/36$

Can anyone explain me this one?

This is a gmat exam question.

Comment: Well, the third odds are quoted in reverse order.  That is, they tell you the chances the third shooter will miss, not hit.  So you've got that factor wrong.

Comment: The odds **against** the third hitting ....

Comment: Error message: "There was a problem parsing the question"